# got an error of TrustManager Vulnerability when updating my app

Tags: android-studio, ssl, android-security

I am updating an app already on playstore and have not changed the SSL code but the aupdate is rejected. I get the error of TrustManager vulnerability. Below is the code that implements TrustManager. The app is using data from two base URLs, any hack on this?

public class SSLTrust {

```
public static void nuke() {
    try {
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {
                new X509TrustManager() {
                    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                        X509Certificate[] myTrustedAnchors = new X509Certificate[0];
                        return myTrustedAnchors;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) throws CertificateException  {
                        try {
                            certs[0].checkValidity();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            throw new CertificateException("Certificate not valid or trusted.");
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) throws CertificateException{
                        try {
                            certs[0].checkValidity();

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            throw new CertificateException("Certificate not valid or trusted.");
                        }

                    }
                }
        };

        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession arg1) {

                String text    =
                        "This is the text to be searched " +
                                "for occurrences of the http:// pattern.";

                String patternString = ".*https://.*";

                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);

                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

                if(!hostname.equalsIgnoreCase(Config.GETAFFILIATION_URL)
                        ||!hostname.equalsIgnoreCase(Config.SENDDATATODB_URL2)
                        
                        ||!hostname.equalsIgnoreCase(Config.GETUSERMFLCODE_URL)){

                    return true;

                }
                else{

                    return false;
                }

            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

As I see you have not trusted anything.
If you want to trust SSL of an URL by yourself.
Firstly, you must download certificate of that site. It is a .cer file, then save that file in a /res/raw folder in your source code.
And in your trust SSL function, you need to use this file to compare with URL that the app is opening.
Check the below link:
https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl#SelfSigned

Comment: Thanks, I trusted let me re.edit the question to include the whole code

Comment: I saw that you are trusting by comparing the URL is being opened with your domain. It is not right way. As I told in the comment, firstly you need to download the crt file. https://prnt.sc/10pit77 . And follow Google's source code for trusting it : https://prnt.sc/10pityv . Hope that can help you

Comment: what if I go the route of downloading the certificate and going the route of adding network configuration file then I remove the TrustManager code. Will this work

Comment: I don't know why you must trust certificate by yourself. For make sure that your app will work well for both cases, you need to test it.